# How to stop space bar from clicking button

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, button, motorola

I'm using VS 2008.  In either a Windows or Smart Device project, pressing Space bar key when a button currently has the focus will cause the button to be clicked and it will raise the `Click` event. Is there any property or setting which will cause it to skip it so that the space bar does not cause a button click?

Answer (score 5):

You can use the Form's KeyPreview property along with the KeyDown event to catch the space bar before it is passed to the button and if the button has focus, then you can mark the key press handled to prevent it from bubbling up:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        MessageBox.Show("Button Clicked")
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.KeyPreview = True
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles MyBase.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Space And Button1.Focused Then
        e.Handled = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: it still has button action.